# BLOB size doubling

Tags: mysql, jdbc, encoding, blob

I am storing a "blob" of 2mb size in my database using jdbc. The max_packet_allowed size is 4MB. But it is throwing a packet too big exception.and the size of the blob doubling in the process. I don't know why